# Can you explain how this KATA strap connector works?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag

I just bought a Kata backpack, MiniBee-110 PL. It has an enormously long waist strap that I think is removable. It's attached to the bag by this connector (in the picture below), but I haven't been able to manipulate it so it snaps open. Before I get too aggressive and break something I thought I would ask the question: Can someone recommend a solution for operating this connector (or if it's even possible to open it)?

[image]

Update
Thanks to the suggestion here is the result showing the opened connector. It did require quite a bit of pressure:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you pull up on one tab and push down on the other.

[image]

Comment: Okay. That gave me the courage to try once more with that approach. (I had to ask. For every connector on my car that I disconnect, if I just do what looks obvious, I seem to break them 100% of the time.) I'll put the picture of the disconnected item in my question.